# How to uniquely identify a request in Grails?

Tags: session, grails

The Grails [request](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.0/ref/Servlet%20API/request.html) object is an instance of [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html).  Is there any way to get a unique id from the request object?  My end goal is to store session data specific to a request, so I need a `String` or number that I can use as a unique identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a static ThreadLocal inside a filter?

Comment: After doing some reading on filters I don't think the use of `ThreadLocal` will even be necessary.  I didn't realize I could store arbitrary data in `request` (which is limited to the request scope) just like I can with `session`.  After I have done all the request processing I can just use a filter with `afterView` and modify the `response` buffer as I see fit.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe add a unique id just as a request attribute?

```
request.setAttribute('UID', Math.random())
```

Comment: Yes.  I didn't realize till last night that I could use `request` like `session` to store data.  My need to uniquely identify a request came up because I was trying to limit the scope of session data to a request, which isn't necessary because request can hold arbitrary data as well!  Thanks!